VSCode not launching the same based on launch context
VS Code:
Version: 1.92.2 (user setup)
Commit: fee1edb8d6d72a0ddff41e5f71a671c23ed924b9
Date: 2024-08-14T17:29:30.058Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

When I open a project from the Explorer Context Menu it does not fully load all the features/extensions, like copilot and other add-ons which are enabled.
But when I launch VSCode from the Task Bar, the full-featured application loads. Why? It should be the same from both launch contexts.
